# strutstestcase - how to specify location of web.xml and struts.xml in war files

Tags: jboss, junit, struts

I am using MockStrutsTestCase to test some of my action classes using **JUnit EE** and **JBoss**. The problem is that its not able to locate the web.xml and struts-config.xml files (when deployed on the server). The directory structure of the ear file being deployed is simple enough.. The ear file breaks up into a jar file containing all java files and a war file containing all WEB-INF directly. So, if I do

```
setConfigFile("WEB-INF/struts-config.xml");
setServletConfigFile("WEB-INF/struts-config.xml");
```

This should point it to the locations of corresponding xml files. But it gives a MalFormedUrlException, etc.

When I am testing the action class without deploying it on the server, and I specify the path of contextDirectory on the local file system, it works fine. So, I gather that I am not able to give the correct location of the files when deployed on the server.

Also, is it that MockStrutsTestCase can't be used for testing on server ? Or do I have to use CactusStrutsTestCase ?

Answer (score 0):

try something like

```
setConfigFile("WEB-INF/classes/struts-config.xml");
```

Comment: The struts-config file is not inside the classes folder...its directly inside WEB-INF....Also, can MockStrutsTestCase be used for testing on the server, or CactusStrutsTestCase be used

Comment: when we deploy war file then the built that is deployed on server makes a new folder "classes" and all your source packages will be moved into this. So the struts.xml file will also be present in this. You can check the structure of war file that is deployed on your server.

Comment: There is no classes folder under WEB-INF in the structure of my war file